# Can't upload Images for my New Product in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created my custom store view **View1**. And specified the image placeholder in the configuration settings.

Now while I add a new product all mandatory fields are filled. But when I add images 
I get this error **"Image type and information need to be specified for each store view."**

Since I have added the placeholder image it appears as default but I want to add my own custom image.
Please help me. **I got a due on 13/6/2013**

And the product entered is saved in database PHPMyadmin. Also when I click default placeholder image I can't see my product in front-end.

I am working on version 1.7.0.2 on Windows Seven

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/45395/#t170830 please try this

Comment: i still can't get this done...i have this option use default value. but can't add images

Answer (score 0):

use Mozila or Just Rename your `.htaccess` file inside the `/media` directory to `.htaccess-old`.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use a browser with flash plugin installed (ex: chromium) the buttons will not display. What you need to do is to use a browser with the flash plugin (ex: google-chrome).

If you are on chromium, you can use the developer tools (F12) and you will see if the error come from missing flash plugin.